# eclipse error opening registry key

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

I got eclipse on my new laptop. I installed both JRE 7 and JDK 1.7, and they are both up to date. When I tried to open eclipse 3 error messages occured:

Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment

Can someone please help me,
Thanks

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19366802/1091466

Comment: I tried this.It worked well for me and it's really very easy.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key