# Java 9: java.dll not found

Tags: java, java-9

After installing Java 9 from https://jdk9.java.net/ (9 Build b85), and running: `java` I got error message

> java.dll not found

Comment: [Error when checking Java version: could not find java.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9313353)

Comment: Generally this error happens when you have multiple versions of Java installed and the DLLs put in the system32 folder do not match with the version of Java that is found first on the search path. Do a test and run java from the bin folder directory, probably it will work