# Java Error opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'

Tags: java, java-runtime-compiler

When running "java -version" on command prompt Windows 7, i get this:

```
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

I have already checked environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin
```

And `PATH` includes `"%JAVA_HOME%`

I have also tried deleting files :
java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe in `ProgramData\Oracle\JAVA\Javapath`
However, they won't delete. Even though I am an administrator.

I have also checked `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SYSWOW64` and didnt find java.exe, javaw.exe or javaws.exe to delete.

What else can I try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when checking Java version: could not find java.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313353/error-when-checking-java-version-could-not-find-java-dll)

Comment: @GeorgeZ I Tried all solutions suggested on that page, none worked for me

Comment: Have you tried removing the ProgramData\Oracle location from your PATH?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes

Comment: 1. Do you have multiple Java installed? 2. What is there in registry key? Does the version specified in the registry key match with your JDK/JRE folder name? 3. `JAVA_HOME` should be the path excluding `bin` and PATH should include `bin` as `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` 4. Are there duplicate entries in `PATH` and also duplication between user and system variables? 5. Can you directly go (cd) to JDK/JRE bin directory where `java` executable is present and run `java -version`?

Comment: @fiveelements only one Java installed. Not sure where the registry key is, where can i find it? I fixed the paths to match what you said. and when i do java -version in the jdk/jre bin directory it displays the version

Comment: @fiveelements for the path is it %JAVA_HOME%/bin or %JAVA_HOME%\bin? (forward slash or back slash)

Comment: In Windows backward slash is used for directory path so, use `%JAVA_HOME%\bin'. Use `regedit' command to open the registry and look for the key you mentioned in your question. Cleanup/correct it if you see discrepancy.

Comment: I hope you have taken care of System32 and SysWOW64 directories. Ensure to launch a new command prompt after changing environment variables.

Comment: @fiveelements The  registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment' looks to be missing. And yes launching new command each time i make a change

Comment: The key full path is: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion`.

Comment: @fiveelements JavaSoft folder is missing from that location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197181/discussion-between-monkey123-and-fiveelements).

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you have multiple Java installed?
2. What is there in registry key? Does the version specified in the registry key match with your JDK/JRE folder name? Use `regedit` command to open the registry and look for the key you mentioned in your question (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion`). Cleanup/correct the version if you see a discrepancy.
3. `JAVA_HOME` should be the path excluding `bin` and `PATH` should include bin as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
4. Are there duplicate entries in `PATH` and also duplication between user and system environment variables?
5. Can you directly go (cd) to JDK/JRE bin directory where java executable is present and run `java -version`?
6. Lastly, I hope you looked at `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SYSWOW64` directories and removed java.exe and related files.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I uninstalled and old Oracle version of Java. The registry key was deleted but a Java executable remained in a hidden folder. For proper cleanup

(on Windows):

`where java` will reveal the location of the shortcut, e.g., `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe` (notice that this is a hidden folder).

Assuming you wanted to get rid of the old Java version, you can delete this folder, and the corresponding path entry.

Answer (score 1):

This error also comes when the software you are using is of 32-bit and you have a 64-bit version of Java installed which is not compatible with the existing softwares where you want to work. You may also uninstall 64-bit and install the 32-bit version which will resolve the issue.